# What is the source of the liberation story that involves Narada and two ascetics?

Tags: resource

There is a story on liberation, which I like. But unfortunately, I do not know the source. Can someone please help? In short, the story goes something like this. Once Narada met two ascetics. He said to one ascetic that it would take three more births for him to attain liberation. The man got frustrated. On the other hand, when Narada told the other guy that it would take as many births as there are leaves on the tamarind tree. He was indifferent to that. Then Narada disclosed that he already attained liberation. You can read the full story here -

https://moralstories26.com/narada-muni-stories-two-sanyasi/

Comment: The art style is definitely same as that of iskon's painting so it can be one of sri sukdev goswami ji's story or anyother iskon related gurus still I cannot be sure. So I guess u have to wait for an answer here. .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the source. This story was narrated by Sri Ramakrishna. It can be found in his Gospel.

Reference-

Sri Ramakrishna and His Gospel Vol. 3 by Swami Bhuteshananda (Appendix I) published by Advaita Ashrama.